# Looking for component/s to split 24v to all of 12v, 5v, 3.3v

Tags: power-supply, dc-dc-converter

I'm still learning and messing with electrical engineering so please keep answers easy to understand.

I'm looking for a component or set of components that I can use to split a 24v power line into multiple power lines at 12v, 5v & 3v. also what these components called. are they just called `dc-dc-converters`?

Comment: How much current do you need? Buck regulators. Linear regulators and zener diodes are all options.  This order is least to most simple but also most to least efficient.  The current you need will determine the best choice.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, im looking at powering an Arduino, MFRC522, 12 Volt magnet door lock, from a single plug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are indeed called DC-DC converters.

You can check at 7812, 7805 and 7803 ICs.

See [Wikipedia 78xx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/78xx) for more information about these ICs.

Comment: There are all-in-one DC-DC bricks though

Comment: The maglocks I use draw 500mA at 12V, that means 6W generated as heat by a 7812. Not ideal in these days of environmental conscience. But they can be wired for 24V instead, much better.

Comment: There was no current specified so my answer is indeed more value for lower current; 500 mA seems quite a lot and so it would result in a lot of heat (loss).